# How to create a Matlab matrix (100 x 100) with random distribution of numbers 1 and 3, when each column must have 10% of 1 and 90% of 3?

Tags: matlab

How can I create in Matlab a matrix (100 x 100) with random distribution of numbers 1 and 3, when in each column I must have 10% of numbers 1 and 90% of numbers 3? this must be random distribution.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v = [1*ones(10,1) ; 3*ones(90,1)];
A = zeros(100,100);
for i = 1:100,
   A(:,i) = v(randperm(100));
end
```

or without a `for` loop

```
A = zeros(100,100);
v = [1*ones(10*100,1) ; 3*ones(90*100,1)];
A(:) = v(randperm(100*100));
```

Though the first one might be better if you want to explicitly control the columns differently later.

Edit: Actually, one subtle point.  The first piece of code guarantees each column to have exactly 10 1's and exactly 90 3's.  the second piece of code doen't make this guarantee, only that the entire matrix has 1000 1's and 9000 3's.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years since I was a Matlab TA, but you should also be able to do it this way:

```
v = [1*ones(10*100,1) ; 3*ones(90*100,1)];
v = reshape( v(randperm(length(v))) ,100,100)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers from @ChrisA and @JosephLust will give you an array in which each column has *exactly* 10 1's and 90 3's, in a random order. That may be what you need, but since you mention that it must be a random distribution, perhaps what you instead want is that each column should contain entries that have a 10% chance of being 1, and a 90% chance of being 3 (which is not the same).

If you want the latter, try this:

```
vals = [1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3];
idx = randi(10,100,100);
data = vals(idx);
```

The middle line creates a 100x100 matrix where each entry is a random integer between 1 and 10. This is then used to index into the array of values, one of which is 1 and nine of which are 3.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for the advice, but actually I need only the values, 1 and 3, because they are values to complete a experimental design plan, for future modelling, so they are factors. But was really nice to know a different approach. thanks!

Comment: "in each column I must have 10% of numbers 1 and 90% of numbers 3"